# Active Directory - Only show accessible shares

Tags: active-directory, network-share, directory-listing

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server running Active Directory and sharing folders over the network.

Every user can list all shares, even if the don't have the right to access them.

This is not a security issue, but when the number of shared folders increases, this can become quite messy.

Is there a simple way to list only folders with access granted ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set the visibility of shares on a per-user or per-group basis. You can hide shares entirely by having their names end with a `$`, but that will affect all users. And you can enable [access-based enumeration](http://blogs.technet.com/b/hugofe/archive/2010/06/21/windows-2008-access-based-enumeration-abe.aspx) on the share. That won't hide the share itself, but will hide any content that the user isn't allowed to access. You enable it in "Share and Storage Managment" in the the advanced SMB settings.